# Why is avahi-daemon excessively spamming my log files?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vps

My VPS provider recently suspended my account for "participating in a DoS attack". Since I've naturally done no such thing, I can only assume it was a security breach, and am now investigating what might have happened. Interestingly, my entire / partition is full of `/var/log/syslog` (23 gigabytes of logs, to be precise), almost exclusively containing variations on the following three lines:

```
Jul 18 21:24:47 <host> avahi-daemon[<pid>]: Withdrawing workstation service for vnet<increasing number>.

Aug  2 16:58:35 <host> avahi-daemon[<pid>]: Registering new address record for <ipv4 or ipv6 address> on eth0.*.

Aug  2 16:58:35 <host> avahi-daemon[<pid>]: Withdrawing address record for <ipv4 or ipv6 address> on eth0.
```

These entries have been appearing for quite a while, at an interval of about five lines in 1½ hours. However, starting around the end of July (unfortunately, due to the sheer volume of the log file I can't get at the exact date), the first message stops appearing and the rate increases dramatically to several tens of lines per second. `/var/log/messages` also contains about 100 megabytes of "dropping messages from that avahi process due to rate limiting".

The VPS is a Linux vServer-based thing, running 32 bit Debian stable.

What might be causing this?

Comment: Why would you even have avadi-daemon running on a public internet accessible server? You should disable it as there is no use in having it running on such servers.

Comment: `aptitude remove avahi-daemon`, often pulled in by a recommends line during sun-java6-bin installation.

Comment: @DanD. I was wondering the exact same thing. It's been a few years since I set this thing up, so I don't remember much or why *anything* is installed on it. Going to wipe the thing and start over from a clean slate, now that I've got a good excuse to get off my lazy ass and do so.